# Cross Join two Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Please see the image here]

I want to Join these two Columns in Google sheets so that each cell of column A is Joined to all the values of Column B. Thanks

Labels                Dates

```
Ess Performance        7/1/2019

DV3-Retargeting         7/2/2019

Facebook WCA            7/3/2019

DV3-Retargeting          7/4/2019

DV3-Retargeting          7/5/2019

DV3-Retargeting          7/6/2019

DV3-Retargeting          7/7/2019

Facebook LAL            7/8/2019

DV3-Retargeting         7/9/2019

FiddeAds            7/10/2019

                    7/11/2019
                    7/12/2019
                    7/13/2019
                    7/14/2019
                    7/15/2019
                    7/16/2019
                    7/17/2019
                    7/18/2019
                    7/19/2019
                   7/20/2019
                    7/21/2019
                     7/22/2019
                      7/23/2019
                      7/24/2019
                      7/25/2019
                      7/26/2019
                     7/27/2019
                       7/28/2019
                     7/29/2019
                     7/30/2019
                     7/31/2019
```

Output I want to see

```
Ess Performance         07-01-2019

DV3-Retargeting     07-01-2019

Facebook WCA            07-01-2019

DV3-Retargeting         07-01-2019

DV3-Retargeting         07-01-2019

DV3-Retargeting         07-01-2019

DV3-Retargeting         07-01-2019

Facebook LAL            07-01-2019

DV3-Retargeting         07-01-2019

FinddAds            07-01-2019
```

So on...........

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please see [the guide on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question so that others can understand what you are trying to do, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Cross Join in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403168/sql-cross-join-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I fully understood what you try to achieve, but see if this helps

```
=ArrayFormula(split(substitute(transpose(split(join(" ", query(split(join(char(10), filter(substitute(C2:C, " ", "|"), len(D2:D))&char(10)), char(10))&"_"&text(filter(D2:D, len(D2:D)), "yyyy-mm-dd"),,9^9)), " ")), "|"," "), "_"))
```

Comment: These are two different columns and need to be in different columns... Can you please have a look at picture?

Comment: What about sharing a copy of your spreadsheet? That would surely be more helpful then a picture...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LJX9LsQ9wYikus8Cy_jsl4x1wuLCX7d9qbgaxsr7cXg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udv6f-0pgVzOegJSXgPR1atOF2I9hj--PMmsDjIHm3s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Now you can access this

Comment: Updated the formula. Try the formula in K3 and see if it works?

Comment: I dont see the formula in there................Can you please have a look ... 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1udv6f-0pgVzOegJSXgPR1atOF2I9hj--PMmsDjIHm3s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I had no editing rights previously. I now entered it in K3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this would definitely serve the purpose :)... I would incorporate it in the main file... Thanks